# Does Stopwatch have a maximum time it can run?

Tags: c#

How long can the `Stopwatch` in .NET run? Does it wrap to negative or restart at 0 if it gets to that limit?

Comment: According to my calculations, about 30,000 years.

Comment: the HPET hardware specification demands a 64-bit counter.  Math.Pow(2, 64) is a nice big number.  As pilots of modern spy planes asserted, you'll run out of ass before you run out of gas.

Comment: Its batteries need to be replaced once in a while.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Stopwatch.Elapsed` returns a `TimeSpan`. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.1) for the `MaxValue` of `TimeSpan`:

> The value of this field is equivalent to Int64.MaxValue ticks. The string representation of this value is positive 10675199.02:48:05.4775807, or slightly more than 10,675,199 days.

Comment: Surely it matters - what happens if you ask for `Elapsed` after 10,675,200 days?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `Stopwatch`'s internal value is a `long`, just like `TimeSpan`'s, so the limit is the same.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They are both measuring ticks, so it's the same number with the same precision, min/max values, and representation.

Comment: This answer is correct if your stopwatch frequency equals 10,000,000. This frequency can however change if the underlying timing mechanism changes. Read the remarks on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency(v=vs.110).aspx for all info. If the frequency would change then you probably still have millions of days before the stopwatch hits it maximum.

Comment: @Servy They're actually not measuring ticks in the same unit. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks?view=net-6.0: "Each tick in the DateTime.Ticks value represents one 100-nanosecond interval. Each tick in the ElapsedTicks value represents the time interval equal to 1 second divided by the Frequency."

Answer (score 10):

> For managed code, the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class uses QPC as
> its precise time basis.

When QPC is available, which it [always is on Windows XP or later](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx).

> How often does QPC roll over?
>
> Not less than 100 years from the most recent system boot, and potentially longer based on the underlying hardware timer used. For
> most applications, rollover isn't a concern.

[Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Assuming Microsoft's Windows .NET implementation, this limit is hardware-specific and may be less than the size of a `TimeSpan` or a `long` as the other answers indicated. Still plenty large enough though. Good luck getting your program to run for 100 years!

Comment: Worth adding how QPC is related to stopwatch (because it can use simple `DateTime.Now.Ticks` instead of it).

Answer (score 2):

`Stopwatch` has an `ElapsedTicks` property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks), which has the following remark:

> This property represents the number of elapsed ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. A tick is the smallest unit of time that the Stopwatch timer can measure. Use the `Frequency` field to convert the `ElapsedTicks` value into a number of seconds.

`Stopwatch.Frequency` is **10000000** on my system. Given the calculation `long.MaxValue / Stopwatch.Frequency / 3600 / 24 / 365` results in **29247**, that is 29247 (floored) years of 365 days (which obviously they aren't always, but I guess it's close enough).

I also checked the source of current .NET and reflected upon .NET Framework and both use a `long` field `elapsed` which it uses to keep track of the elapsed time in the paused state. However, in the running state it uses a `startTimeStamp` and diffs the current timestamp with the start timestamp and adds previously elapsed time from the `elapsed` field. However even if the current timestamp returned by the system would have overflowed this should still return the proper result, as long as total elapsed ticks (expressed in `Stopwatch.Frequency` units, not `DateTime.Ticks`) fits in a `long`.

Last but not least, in `Stopwatch.Stop()` there's a check if the elapsed value is negative and if it is it's reset to 0. There's a comment mentioning this is possible under certain circumstances (bugs in BIOS or HAL, according to the comment) when very small intervals are measured, but the same obviously applies when `elapsed` overflows and becomes negative.

Answer (score 0):

`StopWatch` uses `long` data type whose max limit is -

> 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

So this is the max time(ticks) it can run.

Although it would take years to complete this time.

Comment: Not DateTime, 2 bits are used to keep track of the Kind property.